# I can not get this subjective map regarding a Field and a quotient group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $ F=\{ a+b \sqrt3 \space | \space a,b \in \mathbb {Q} \} $ i have proved this is a field already.

I also had to prove that R was a ring 
$ R = \{i+j\sqrt 3 \space | \space i,j \in \mathbb {Z} \} $

next i had to show that if Q is the field of quoetients for R that  $ \forall [a,b] \in Q$

$ [a,b] = [c,k] $ where $ c\in R$ and $ k \in \mathbb {Z} $ k can't be zero.

the square brackets denote equivalence classes. ( also done)

The last thing i have to do is define an isomorphism from F to Q and show that it is surjective ( nothing else just surjective.)

I managed to get to this point of even defining the isomorphism but i can't show its surjective.

let $a+b \sqrt3 \in F$  now since a,b are ration we can write this in the following way. $ a+b \sqrt3= \frac{m}{n} + \frac {s}{r} \sqrt3 =\frac{mr+sn\sqrt3}{nr} $ since this is true for all elements in F i define the map $f(a+b\sqrt3) \to [(mr+sn\sqrt3) , nr] $ where  $ [(mr+sn\sqrt3) , nr] \in Q$ since nr is an interger and the top is an element in the ring.

but i cannot for the life me show this map is surjective i know that i can write every equivalence class of a pair (i,j) in Q as [c,k] where c is in the ring and k is in the integers but and i can even show that i can write everything in the field as an element in that form but i can't show that i get all of them hit in Q by coming from the field.

Comment: Oh, $Q$ isn't the rationals.  I misread.  Not sure I get the bracket definition of your $Q$, but it's enough to just take it to be the field of quotients for $R$, yes?

Comment: How do you define a stupid subjective map?

Comment: $[c,k]=[i + j \sqrt{3},k]$ for $i,j\in\mathbb{Z}$, so $[c,k]$ is image of $(i/k)+(j/k)\sqrt{3}$?

Comment: @lulu yes. Ramus The same way you define a subjective map its just more annoying.

Comment: @ancientmathematician yes but k is also an integer in that part. your welcome to define the map directly to Q of R if thats easier

Comment: then you'd just write it as $[a,b] = \frac {a}{b} | a,b \in R $

Comment: So, just show that every element of $Q$ can be written as an element of $R$ divided by an integer.  The isomorphism is just inclusion ($R\subset  Q\implies F\subset  Q$).

Comment: i already did that i. if $[a,b] \in Q $ where a,b are in R. i prove that $ [a,b] = [c,k] $ where c is an element in the ring and k is an integer. let c= the conjugate of b times a ie c=b'a that reduces us to c in R over k in the integers i cant show this map is onto

Comment: i tried writing a function f that took every element in F to an equivalence class in Q  since it was an arbitrary element i said it was true for all elements in F. then i defined a function g that took all the equivalence class's of Q to F and showed that they all had something to land on. is that enough to show that f is onto?

Comment: I don't see the problem.  I need to show that every element of $Q$ can be written as an element in the quotient field of $R$, yes?  So take $\alpha=a+b\sqrt 3\in Q$.  If $a=\frac mn, b=\frac rs$ for integers $m,n,r,s$ then $\alpha = \frac {ms+rn\sqrt 3}{ns}$.  But the numerator is in $R$ and the denominator is in $\mathbb Z$.  So inclusion hits all of $Q$.

Comment: The problem is that im an idiot.i actually had all the pieces written down i just didnt believe i had everything  to show that mathimagically they were the same. thank you the subset hint actually was enough for me to eventually figure out that i had what i needed. your welcome to post it as an answer and ill accept.

Comment: Oh, no problem.  These things can get very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that every element in $Q$ can be written as

$$\frac {a + b \sqrt 3} {c + d \sqrt 3} = \frac {(a + b \sqrt 3) (c - d \sqrt 3)} {(c + d \sqrt 3) (c - d \sqrt 3)} = \frac {(ac - 3bd) + (bc - ad) \sqrt 3} {c^2 - 3 d^2} = \\
\frac {(ac - 3bd)} {c^2 - 3 d^2} + \frac {(bc - ad)} {c^2 - 3d^2} \sqrt 3 \in F ,$$

so $Q \subseteq F$.

On the other hand, notice that $\sqrt 3$ is algebraic over $\Bbb Q$, being a root of $X^2 - 3 \in \Bbb Q[X]$. This means that $F = \Bbb Q [\sqrt 3] = \Bbb Q (\sqrt 3)$ and that $F$ is the smallest field that contains $\Bbb Q$ and $\sqrt 3$. Since $Q$ obviously contains $\Bbb Q$ and $\sqrt 3 = \frac {\sqrt 3} 1$, the minimality of $F$ implies $Q \supseteq F$.

We have shown therefore that $F \supseteq Q$ and $F \subseteq Q$, which means that $F = Q$. The isomorphism that you want then is simply the identity, which is obviously surjective.